# Grouping rows with each different row has header row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to group some data in SQL Server. However not sure if there is a query that can do this. Below is the original data

```
Type    Number      Date            Result
Car     6664441111  Feb 22 2016     IVR Detected
Car     6664441111  Feb 22 2016     Answered
Lab     5552221111  Feb 22 2016     No Answer
Lab     5552221111  Feb 22 2016     Hangup
Lab     5552221111  Feb 22 2016     Answered
```

I would like to know a query that can do this:

```
Type    Number      Date            Result    
Car     6664441111  Feb 22 2016     IVR Detected
        6664441111  Feb 22 2016     Answered
Lab     5552221111  Feb 22 2016     No Answer
        5552221111  Feb 22 2016     Hangup
        5552221111  Feb 22 2016     Answered
```

I am using SQL Server. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you need to do that? That looks like something that should be done in the display layer of your application, not in the database layer.

Comment: To @TomH point, the request really looks like a "roll-up" report that can be easily done with SSRS, Crystal, etc.

Comment: Note that what reporting tools refer to as *grouping* is not the same thing as `group by` in a sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuimg your data is sorted already and doesn't need to be sorted to make your logic happen you could use a `row_number` window function:

```
select
  CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN type END AS type, number, date, result
from (
  select type, number, date, result, row_number() over (partition by type) AS row_num
  from t
  ) x
```

If you need to order your data to appear like in your example, you need to add `order by` within window function.